# Есть ли хорошие книги по обработке ошибок?

Tags: c++, веб-программирование

Вопрос вроде очевидный, но конкретного чего-то не находил пока. Обычно в книгах уделено этому пара абзацев в духе "вот вам try-catch, выглядит оно так" - удачи. Зато по всей книге всегда есть упоминания в духе "обработка ошибок крайне важна и должна быть изначально продумана/встроена в проект/класс на начальном этапе".

Но не встречал ещё, чтобы особо рассказывалось об этом и, главное, как к этому делу подходить, с какого бока. Не будешь же подряд всё покрывать try-catch и повсеместно писать error коды на каждую строку кода. Есть ли по данной теме полезные книги, например, на уровне тех, что занимаются описанием ООП в целом (тот же Вайсфельд). Чтобы осознать тему концептуально-философски сначала. Или может есть книги, которые одновременно цепляют тестирование программ и обработку ошибок? Вроде эти две темы, кажется, обязаны быть связанными.

Желательно, чтобы книга не была связана жёстко с конкретным языком (или хотя бы не уходить сильно далеко от C++ и веба) и не быть талмудом на 1400 страниц. Хотя всё это не критично, конечно.

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Не встречал книг по такой теме, обычно обработка ошибок - это просто одна из глав книг типа «чистого кода» роберта мартина или «совершенного кода» маконнела.

Comment: Мне кажется, самый секретный момент при обработке ошибок - это то, как связан try-catch с разверткой стека, что то наподобие https://glebradchenko.susu.ru/courses/bachelor/oop/2014/SUSU_OOP_11_exceptions_RAII.pdf

Comment: просмотел эту "презентацию".  "Не стоит пытаться передавать исключения за тело конструктора". А что делать с объектом в этом случае - не рассказано. Звести переменную "не инициализировано" и проверять (это известный неверный подход, даже std::ifstream успел заразится). Но потом я увидел auto_ptr и все стало на свои места.